# ES6 this is undefined inside object literal function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async.js

I am trying to run `async.parallel` inside an ES6 class like this:

```
public getConsole(req: Request, res: Response) {
    async.parallel({
        count: this.getDocumentCount,
        collectionSize: this.getCollectionMb
    }, 
    (err, results) => {
        res.json(results);
    })
}
```

but this is undefined. I can't do `. . . this.getDocumentCount.bind(this)` because this is still undefined in that context. I also can't do

```
    async.parallel({
        count: this.getDocumentCount,
        collectionSize: this.getCollectionMb
    }.bind(this), 
    (err, results) => {
        res.json(results);
    })
}
```

because typescript complains.

Comment: See "Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks / event handlers" in the duplicate.

Comment: `this.getDocumentCount.bind(this)` should work fine if `getConsole` is properly defined in the class and `getConsole` is called correctly. `{ ... }.bind(this)` cannot work because `.bind` is a method on functions, not objects.